# What happens if everybody dies on a survival round in Fall Guys?

Tags: fall-guys-ultimate-knockout

When you have an elimination game, I always wonder... Like if everybody screws up at the memory game... how does the game handle it?

Will the game stop just before the last fall guy hits the goo declaring him the winner, or will the show result in a tie?

Comment: I only found a video of a team game where somehow both teams lost, and it resulted in no one being declared a winner... at least that is what it looks like, despite is saying the person was a winner in the top left. A somewhat comical scene shows one of the fall guys get hit with the crown and knocked off the podium https://youtu.be/p6K7I-KAYWs?t=246.

Comment: There is also a Mr Beast video where Chris and another player fell at the same time into the goo, but Chris won as he is the last to hit the goo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the eliminated number is always short of one, I would guess the round would stop before the last fall guy is eliminated. Making him the victor.

And with the @TimmyTim video, it would seem the game has not a tie mode. If there is no winner by glitch, the user is given the cutscene that he won.

Answer (score 0):

In Jump Showdown, if you are the last two and you both knocked off around the same time, whoever hits the slime last wins. I imagine other levels are similar. Not sure what happens if, say, no one finishes see saw before the timer runs out.

Comment: The races timeout might be 'after the first one has finished' like GTA (even if in GTA its after the first 50% finish) Dodging that problem.